# Suppose a die is thrown .Write two events which are ..

Tags: probability

Suppose a die is tossed. Write two events which are:

a. Exhaustive and mutually exclusive.

b. Exhaustive but not mutually exclusive.

c. Exhaustive but not equally likely

**My input :**

a. Events are :

$A=$ Getting even number when die is thrown.

$B=$ Getting odd number when die is thrown.

b. Events are :

$A=$ Getting number less than $5$ when die is thrown.

$B=$ Getting multiple of $2$ when die is thrown.

Did I write them correctly?

c. I am stuck at this one. Honestly, I didn't understand the "not equally likely or equally likely". Please, someone, tell me the meaning of it and one example of it too. Don't give an example related to this particular question, after getting understanding of it I 'll try to make one by myself.

Comment: An unrelated example of "exhaustive but not equally likely" would be...suppose you flip a fair coin twice.  let $A$ be the event "you get $TT$".  Let $B$ be the event "you get at least one $H$".

Comment: @lulu I should write an explanation too. I will edit my question thx.

Comment: Note:  I revised my comment to make my example unrelated to your question.  Also, I realized I had misread your question.  Your first example is good, but your second is not as the event $\{5\}$ does not appear.

Comment: Note: there is no need for an event to be such a nice rule. Your first event could also be written as $A=\{\,2,4,6\,\}$.

Comment: @Babelfish I just thought it would seem formal to my professor.

Comment: In c) you are asked to mention two events such that it is for certain that at least one of the events will occur, and secondly they must have distinct probability to occur.

Comment: @drhab It means Event A: Getting number less than or equal to 4 has a probability \frac{4}{6}. and another event B: Getting number 5 or 6 has a probability \frac{2}{6}. Both events have a different probability which means they are not equally likely to occur. I get it right?

Comment: That is a correct example. Btw, it is not forbidden (and also not needed) here that both events can occur (as is the case in a)).

Comment: @drhab I didnt get you. Could you please write it in more simple language ?

Comment: Again (the main thing): your example is correct. Another correct answer would have been: the event that a number $\leq6$ (has probability $1$) is thrown together with the event a number $\leq5$ is thrown (has probability $5/6\neq1$). In that case both events can occur and that is allowed here because it is not demanded that the events are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @drhab ohh I get it. You are saying there is no hard and fast rule to express examples the way I did .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let S be the universal set

Set S :{1,2,3,4,5,6}

Set A :{your choice}      $A   \in\ S$

Set B :{your choice}   $B   \in\ S$

Exhaustive Events: You can choose any way you want to define A and B such that $A\cup\ B$ = S
Example :

|A ={1} B={2,3,4,5,6}|

|A ={1,3} B={2,4,5,6}|

|A ={1,2,5,6} B={3,4}|

|A ={1,2,3,6} B={2,3,4,5}|

|A ={1,2,3} B={2,3,4,5,6}|

|A ={1,2,3,4,5} B={1,2,3,4,5,6}| .....

Mutually Exclusive : You can choose any way you want to define A and B such that $A \cap\ B$ = $\phi\   $

i.e. There should be no common element between A and B

Example :

|A ={1} B={2,3,4,5,6}|

|A ={1,3} B={2,4,5,6}|

|A ={1,2,5,6} B={3,4}|

|A ={1,2,3} B={4,5}|

|A ={1} B={2,3}|

|A ={1,6} B={2,4,5}| .....

Equally likely: It means the probability of occurring of events A and B is same

Here probability is determined by the size of set A and B.

For equally likely both sets have the same size

Examples for  equally likely

|A ={1,2,3} B={2,3,4}|

|A ={1,3} B={4,5}|

|A ={1,2} B={1,2}|

|A ={1,3,5} B={2,4,6}|

|A ={1} B={6}|

|A ={1,4,5,6} B={2,3,4,5}| .....